# When trying to log in to app getting we're sorry, something went wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have the logs and one error at the bottom I have tried rake db migrate. which didn't work either.

2017-01-28T17:08:44.257358+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/sign_in" host=www.pointsonpaper.com request_id=17ca7be4-c859-47ba-b680-fc1d13a2aaaf fwd="104.57.187.118" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=690ms status=500 bytes=906

Answer (score 0):

eo you have a rails app deployed on heroku? If so, 
well on heroku you should run

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

However, to be more precise you should show your logs. 
Run heroku logs in your terminal and post the actual error here.

Comment: getting this now 2017-01-28T17:33:03.207790+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake dyno_ping` by user scheduler@addons.heroku.com

Comment: ran this :heroku run rake db:migrate got this-
Running rake db:migrate on ⬢ pointsonpaper... up, run.5492 (Hobby)
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:163: warning: already initialized constant Mime::PDF
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:163: warning: previous definition of PDF was here
  MOPED: Could not resolve IP for: oceanic.mongohq.com:10020 runtime: n/a

Comment: Are you using rails 4.1? Can you upgrade to rails 4.2?

Comment: whats this mean               MOPED: Could not resolve IP for: oceanic.mongohq.com:10020 runtime: n/a